# Why are the following considered memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me why the following lines are showing as having memory leaks within Instruments:

```
self.videoEngine = [[VideoEngine alloc] initWithCallbackName:@"IntroFinished"];

self.videoEngine = [[VideoEngine alloc] initWithCallbackName:@"MainMovieFinished"];

self.timerMap = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fps target:self selector:@selector(updateAnimationTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSString *locationName2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[locationName substringFromIndex:test]];
```

Is there an issue with not using a pre-set NSString when initialising? In the examples of self.videoEngine and self.timerMap they both have (nonatomic, retain) properties and are synthesised before use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your not using Arc (Which with the retain mentioned, i presume your not) then that will be your memory leak.

When you assign the VideoEngine property it is doing another retain on your object.  You need to add autorelease to then end of you alloc statements.

```
self.videoEngine = [[[VideoEngine alloc] initWithCallbackName:@"IntroFinished"] autorelease];

self.videoEngine = [[[VideoEngine alloc] initWithCallbackName:@"MainMovieFinished"] autorelease];

self.timerMap = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fps target:self selector:@selector(updateAnimationTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSString *locationName2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[locationName substringFromIndex:test]];
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why I need to autorelease them even though I release them later? I also thought the point in self. was to see if the pointer was equal to the new value, and if not to release it? I'm getting really confused now...

Comment: When you alloc an object like you are with VideoEngine the object has a retain count of one.  And because your property is declared as  (nonatomic, retain) it will also increase the retain count of an object when it is assigned.

Comment: Oh okay, so if I do the follow: VideoEngine *ve = [[VideoEngine alloc] etc], then self.videoEngine = ve; , then [ve release]. That should be fine?